# Camel IMAPS and TIMER components - exclude redundant threads

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I use Camel IMAPS and Timer components.

An emails are received successfully and I can process them using MailboxConsumer.

And Timer is starting some processing using MyConsumer bean.

The problem is that I need only single thread for every consumer I use.

But the Camel framework provides for me two threads for every consumer I use in my project.

It leads to double processing of the same objects that is harmful for my business logic.

I need advice how to configure camel to consume mailbox in single thread mode (not concurrently).

**My camel-context.xml fragment:**

```
<camelContext id="camel-mailbox" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>my.package</package>
    <endpoint id="mailboxEndpoint" uri="imaps://host?password=****&amp;consumer.delay=60000&disconnect=false&amp;closeFolder=false&amp;peek=false&amp;delete=true&amp;fetchSize=1&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1&amp;mapMailMessage=false&amp;unseen=true"/>
    <route>
        <from uri="timer://myTimer?period=180000"/>
        <setBody><constant></constant></setBody>
        <to uri="bean:myConsumer?method=process"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
<bean class="my.package.MyConsumer" name="myConsumer"/>
<bean class="my.package.MailboxConsumer"/>
```

**MyConsumer class:**

```
public class MyConsumer {
    public synchronized void process(){
        // here my code runs
    }
}
```

**inputMialboxEndpoint consumer:**

```
public class MailboxConsumer {
    @Consume(ref="mailboxEndpoint")
    public synchronized void process(Exchange exchange) {
        // here my code do runs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's runinng in two threads because you have 2 routes. One is directly defined, second is defined using @Consume annotation.

Why you need use only one thread? What's a reason? Maybe you should try to refactor application to thread safe?

But if you really need single thread than maybe you should try something like that:

```
<from uri="timer://myTimer?period=180000"/>
<setBody><constant></constant></setBody>
<setHeader headerName="componentType"><constant>timer</constant></setBody>
<to uri="seda:componentQueue">

<from endpoint="mailboxEndpoint"/>
<setHeader headerName="componentType"><constant>mail</constant></setBody>
<to uri="seda:componentQueue">


<from uri="seda:componentQueue?concurrentConsumers=1">
<choice //here choose component by header and proceed
```

Comment: Kaczy, thank you for help.
I need every endpoint to be processed using only it's separate thread (i.e. one thread per consumer, but by default camel creates 4 threads: every consumer have 2 processing threads). I'll try seda. Thanks a lot.